# Why do I sometimes get increased Fun/Creativity scores after writing the game proposal?

Tags: game-dev-story

Sometimes, if I make one of my employees write the initial pitch of the game, and I get scores between 30-50 in the popup, upon exiting it, the actual game score will be somewhere between 60-100, for no reason I can discern.

Can anybody tell me the reason as to why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experimented with the game and it seems that this occurs only after developing a sequel. It appears that some portion of Fun/Creativity of the previous title in the series carries over to the sequel you are making.